# Extract table data from HTML page in php

Tags: php, html

I have a html table with multiple rows and each row with multiple columns. A Sample for one row looks like this.

```
<table class ="classt">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="row">
            <td height="20" valign="top" class="mosttext-new">data</td>
            <td height="20" valign="top" class="mosttext-new"> data</td>
            <td height="20" valign="top" class="mosttext-new">data</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to extract all td elements like this in a php script.

```
foreach($html->find('table.classt') as $e){
         foreach ($e->find('tr.row') as $tr){
            foreach ($tr->find('td') as $td){
                    $text = $td->innertext;
            }
        }
    }
```

But in $tr I am not getting row details with td tags. It is just coming the entire row withing double quotes like this

"data    data      data"

so my third loop is not able to find td as $tr does not have td tags.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to mention the class name after the 'td' followed by '.' like this

```
 foreach ($tr->find('td.mosttext-new') as $td)
```

Hope this should solve your problem. All the best.

Comment: so my third loop is not able to find td as $tr does not have td tags. From this line what you actually asking? Could not understand what really is your issue. Can you update what output you are expecting?. I tried with your code it's working fine. Update your question then i will answer furtherly.